# Installing a deadbolt lock on a metal door & metal frame

Tags: doors, lock, metal, door-frame, deadbolt

I live in an apartment where the front door and its frame are both metal and hollow inside. I didn't have trouble installing a deadbolt lock with one of the doors because you could remove the strike plate on the latch with one of my locks but the other lock I bought you cannot remove the strike plate.

Does anyone have advice on what I should do to install this strike plate into the door and frame? I thought about simply drilling small holes for to screw in the latch but I come to the issue where the strike plate won't be embedded so I thought I could hammer the strike plate to make a dent into the door and frame but I'm afraid of warping and screwing up the strike plate.

Comment: Return the one lock, get another one like the one that works, done. Beware of "hollow metal doorframes" - they can be easily pried, and should be full of concrete to prevent that, but if your builder was cheap they won't be, and 5 seconds or less with a prybar will spring the frame far enough for the door to be opened. Voice of experience here...

Comment: One simple way to harden the door against prying is to install a surface dead bolt of the kind where the bolts latch vertically (perpendicular to the direction of prying). Here's just a random example to show the style of lock: https://images.homedepot-static.com/productImages/dce9ce3b-d0af-4549-8740-f710a8261931/svn/prime-line-door-reinforcement-u-9970-64_1000.jpg

Comment: @Ecnerwal thanks for the warning, I live in an apartment so I can't do much about replacing the door. I'm having an incomplete picture of what happens when it's pried - does the door bend and is the concrete there to keep it from bending (and you mean fully filled right?)

Comment: @Stanwood oh goodness : \ I was actually replacing those vertical locks with deadbolts. I was afraid that someone could easily kick the door in because those vertical locks are only held on by screws  drilled into the frame and face the direction of the force of opening the door.

Comment: @Stanwood I took a look at how the door lever was installed and it looks like there are metal brackets? that are inside the hole to allow for a faceplate/strikeplate to be installed. I don't see any screws that hold up these brackets though - any idea how they're holding? [This is the door knob](https://i.imgur.com/QCtg4xl.jpg) and [This is the frame](https://i.imgur.com/wiWNRje.jpg). I know it looks ghetto - old apartment.

Comment: The surface dead bolt is usually installed as a supplement to a conventional deadbolt. One resists prying while the other resists movement in the direction of door swing.

Comment: Most hollow door slabs are reinforced near the frame. I’ve never looked inside a metal door but I would expect that any reinforcing brackets on the interior of the door are welded or braised on.

Comment: The doorframe springs away from the door, and without something to stop it (concrete being the way I'm familiar with) can be sprung far enough to release the bolts, often without any permanent bend (i.e. it springs back and appears to be "normal."